# Deduction of alias template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, alias

This question is partially motivated by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75107468/identical-full-template-specialization).

I am aware that [alias templates are not deduced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Alias_templates), except, in c++20, for class template argument deduction.
For this reason, this code does not compile

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool Bv>
struct A;

template <>
struct A<true> {
  void print() const { std::cout << "True" << std::endl; }
};

template <>
struct A<false> {
  void print() const { std::cout << "False" << std::endl; }
};

enum class Btypes : int { cat, dog, wolf };

template <Btypes bt>
using B = A<(bt == Btypes::dog) ? true : false>;

template <Btypes bt>
void callB(const B<bt>& b)
{
  b.print();
}

int main()
{
  B<Btypes::dog> b;
  callB(b); // error: no matching function for call to ‘callB(B<Btypes::dog>&)‘

  return 0;
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41008415/8769985) details some subtleties on how a deduction of alias templates could/or could not work.
I am however interested in a simpler case of non-type template parameters, like in the code above.
It seems to me reasonable that a template deduction could be possible without ambiguities, since the non-type template parameters involved can only take a finite amount of values.

Is there a way, within c++17, to circumvent the lack of template parameter deduction for a class like in the code above, with non-type template parameters?
That is, to make the code legal without changing the definition/signature of the function `callB` (and keeping the alias)?